# Ошибка в коде php

Tags: php

Помогите, пожалуйста. На сервере выявляет ошибку. Вот она:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in z:\home\synape\www\testreg.php on line 27
Warning: mysql_fetch_row(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in z:\home\synape\www\testreg.php on line 45
Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный."
```

Вот половина кода:

```
include ("bd.php");
$ip=getenv("HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR");
if (empty($ip) || $ip=='unknown') {
    $ip=getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
}
mysql_query ("DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 900");
$result = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($myrow['col'] > 2) {
    exit ("Вы набрали логин или пароль неверно 3 раза. Подождите 15 минут до   следующей попытки.");
}
$password = md5($password);
$password = strrev($password);
$password = $password."b3p6f";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND                  password='$password'",$db); 
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if (empty($myrow['id'])) {
    $select = mysql_query ("SELECT ip FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'");
    $tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);
    if ($ip == $tmp[0]) {
        $result52 = mysql_query("SELECT col FROM oshibka WHERE ip='$ip'",$db);
        $myrow52 = mysql_fetch_array($result52);
        $col = $myrow52[0] + 1; 
        mysql_query ("UPDATE oshibka SET col=$col,date=NOW() WHERE ip='$ip'");
    }
```

А ошибка в коде здесь:

`$myrow= mysql_fetch_array($result);`  и  `$tmp= mysql_fetch_row($select);`

Comment: Подключение к БД покажите.

Answer (score 1):

переменная $db не валидна, скорей всего из за того что не произошло подключение к бд.

Comment: и что делать

Comment: проверить подключение к базе, и mysql_query() использует два параметра, первый строка запроса, второй $db, но никак не только строку, что тоже может вызывать эту ошибку.

Comment: @FLK, с каких пор нельзя не передавать указатель запроса?

Comment: mysql_query ("DELETE FROM oshibka WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date) > 900");
вот это

Comment: @антон В базе mysql вы создали таблицу с названием oshibka?

Comment: @Construct согласен, я не прав слишком обобщил, давно не пользовался mysql_query, тем не менее в данном примере, если mysql_query не найдет адекватного идентификатора соединения с базой она сформирует его самостоятельно с пустыми параметрами, что вернет false который никак не будет являться валидным объектом для mysql_fetch_array, а так как мы не видим кода который выше, то лучше всё таки его указать.

Comment: Извините, но у меня ещё и здесь вылетает ошибка
 $tmp = mysql_fetch_row ($select);

Comment: @антон проверьте подключение к бд, либо покажите код в файле bd.php

Comment: <?php
          $db = mysql_connect ("localhost","user","1234");
           mysql_select_db ("mysq",$db);
           ?>

Comment: а теперь проверьте все данные, скорей всего вы неправильно указали имя базы данных, логично было бы её назвать `mysql` используйте конструкцию типа:

            $db= mysql_connect('localhost','user','1234');
            if (!$db) {
                die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
            }
            $db_selected = mysql_select_db('mysql', $db);
            if (!$db_selected) {
                die ('Can\'t use foo : ' . mysql_error());
            }
чтобы посмотреть ошибки

Answer (score 1):

Этот скрипт взят вот [отсюда](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=37&id=350).
Скрипт из этого урока имеет массу ошибок, но он все же будет корректно работать если довести его до ума. Автор урока допустил огромную ошибку, не указав в пункте №4 как будет называться таблица. Как следует из нижележащего кода название таблицы: oshibka. Возможно ошибка именно в этом. Когда Вы устанавливали сервер, вы действительно вводили именно эти данные или же они взяты из примера localhost","user","1234"?

Comment: Пипец у них там оформление кода отступами- вырви глаз называется. Теперь мне понятно где люди учатся оформлять код.

Comment: нет то что вы видети в коде это мои данные ,но БД называется не  oshibka, mysq